# Execute jQuery before Javascript with oncall

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can one execute the jQuery before this Javascript? Currently, I am getting in the logs `2`, `1` when I would like to get `1`, `2`.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form method="POST" id="post-form">
   <input type="submit" onclick="createDiv();" name="Send" >
</form>

<script>
 $(document).ready(
      $('#post-form').submit(function(e){
  console.log(1);
      })
    );
</script>

<script>
 function  createDiv() {
   console.log(2);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: since the click on the input triggers the submit on the form ... you can't

Comment: @JaromandaX I understand. However, is there a way to get around it? Maybe without explicit usage of `onclick` but with some alternative?

Comment: Move the createDiv call from the onclick event into the submit callback...

Comment: `is there a way to get around it` no - the submit event is triggered by the click event - one follows the other - and yes, what Mina just said ... why do you want submit to run before click

Comment: @GuyIncognito Please, can you be more explicit with an example. I am fairly new to javascript and you would help me a lot.

Comment: If you want createDiv to run after the `console.log(1)` line then call it there. `$('#post-form').submit(function(e){ console.log(1); createDiv(); })`

Comment: @GuyIncognito Thank you very much. I have been searching a solution for more than a day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know first click button event is triggering then form is submitting. Therefore you output is logically correct. But still if wanna change the flow you can do some modification to achieve that.
To ensure that the jQuery code executes before the JavaScript code, you can modify your script as follows:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

  function createDiv() {
    console.log(2);
  }

    $('#post-form').submit(function(e) {
      console.log(1);
      createDiv();
    });
  });
</script>

<form method="POST" id="post-form">
  <input type="submit" name="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: Your 8 most recent answers all appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.